Store Python return value (not print value) in a Jenkins variable
I have a Jenkins pipeline which will execute a python file and get its return value, and store it in a Jenkins variable for use in the later stages. I have seen a lot of posts using sh stage to capture the print output of the python file, but what I want is to store the last return value, rather than the print value. I am even not sure is it possible?
Say my python file looks like this:
def test():
    print ("Line 1")
    print ("Line 2")
    return false

test()

and my jenkins stage looks like this:
stage("run") {
   steps {
       script {
            result = sh (returnStdout: true,
                         script: "python ${python_file_location} "
                         ).trim()

            echo "result: ${result}"
       }
   }
}

This way I am able to capture the first print statement which is "Line 1", but not the return value false.
another alternate Jenkins pipeline is:
stage("run") {
   steps {
       script {
            result = sh (returnStatus: true,
                         script: "python ${python_file_location} "
                         ).trim()

            echo "result: ${result}"
       }
   }
}

with this pipeline, I am able to capture the python file execution status(success or not), but still not the return value.

Yeah, the sh step provides really limited options when it comes to what to return. There is no Jenkins specific way to capture what the sh doesn't return, only what your shell already provides - I/O redirection to a file. It's up to you what to return from the sh and what to save and read later. A few considerations:

If you return the status (aka exit code or return code) your step will always succeed. And it's up to you to check the status and throw an error, but that error will not be attached to the sh step, so the pipeline flow visualization will look somewhat confusing. I would recommend letting the step fail if the script returns a non-zero code and surrounding it with a catchError step.

If you return the standard output (returnStdout: true) nothing gets printed to the logs. If it's a quick command then it might be ok, but if it takes any amount of time you might want to see some progress in the logs. In that case I would recommend to pipe the output to tee and save to a file to read later (blah | tee capture_out.txt)

returnStdout: true takes care of the stdout, not stderr, that still goes to the log. If you need to capture it either redirect it to stdout with 2>&1 or to a file.


All this works in bash, zsh, and dash. If you are using a different shell you would need to figure out how to deal with I/O redirection there.
